# MathJax font without italic

Tags: fonts, mathjax

I want to use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org) with a regular font, not italic. I tried to load different STIX fonts, but the symbols rendered with MathJax are always converted to italic.

I've checked [STIX font FAQ page](http://www.stixfonts.org/STIXfaq.html) and it is supposed to have a regular version, but I can't figure out how to use it with Mathjax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The use of italics is actually an important part of proper mathematical typesetting, so I would recommend that you not override that.  Is there some important reason you are trying to do so?

You don't mention which input format you are using, but if it is TeX, you can use `\mathrm{...}` around your mathematics to get upright variables rather than italic ones.  If you are using MathML, then use `<math mathvariant="normal">...</math>` to get upright letters.  Personally, I find the result ugly, but people's tastes differ.

Comment: It is for a digital physics book. The author asked me specifically to have some of the formulas in regular. I'm using TeX. I tried \mathrm{...} and it's working perfect. Thank you!