# Prevent unnecessary latex formatting?

Tags: latex, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Is there any way to prevent latex from formatting text unnecessarily? Look at this code and the output:

Code:

```
<h2>Acceleration Curve Calcs</h2>

Paddle = .48" <br>
Chain Pitch = .50" <br> 
Pads per minute = 300 p/m <br>

$SecondsPerPad = \frac{60s}{300ea}$
```

Output:

[image]

All I really need from Latex, is the fraction function, but it insists in resizing my text, bolding and italicizing.  I don't about any presentation standard, all I need is the simplest display possible without any extra crap, and division presented vertically.

***EDIT1***

Here's an example following a comment.  I believe this is just too unreadable and distracting for use:

[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate, but I could not find it so: `$\text{SecondsPerPad} = \frac{60s}{300\text{ea}}$`. And let's hope someone else will find the correct duplicate target ;)

Comment: You could always do `SecondsPerPad = $\frac{60s}{300ea}$`, right?

Comment: Never use math mode for whole words - the kerning of `SecondsPerPad` is completely messed up

Comment: @krassowski - look at the font size of 60s/300ea.  Removing the word in this particular example doesn't affect that.  and wrapping everything in `\text` would in my opinion be too ridiculous a solution to consider Latex useful.  I'll add another example, with what you suggest, but the result is, again in my opinion, unreadable and distracting.  Not something I would actually be able to use.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676223/mathjax-font-without-italic

Comment: The `$$`  are not just for latex, but for a latex *math environment*, so this is what you get in the math environment.